# Refactoring a bloated DAO(Data Access Object) pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, refactoring, dao, data-access-layer

So I have implemented the DAO pattern as my data access strategy. Each DAO for a table in my database. Initially, in my User DAO, it looked something like this

```
List<User> GetAllUsers();
Guid Add(User user);
int Delete(Guid id);
int Update(User user);
```

However, it has bloated into something like this now:

```
    List<string> GetAllUserNamesOnly();
    List<User> GetAllUsers();
    User GetByUserId(string userId);
    User GetByUserId(Guid userId);        
    Guid Add(User user);
    int Delete(Guid id);
    int Update(User user);
    int UpdatePartial(User user);
```

And I can only imagine what it'll grow into as I keep adding more methods to scale with incoming business requirements.

Given my current data access strategy, are there anyways I can refactor this so it doesn't bloat up into one difficult-to-maintain mess?

I'm open to suggests from total overhauling (though I'm unlikely to do this) to "quick hacks"

Comment: Use query handlers for your querying needs? Now you'll have more classes instead of more methods